# ModelBuilder models keep getting broken/corrupt

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4

I've got a problem with my ArcMap 10.4 ModelBuilder:

Whenever ModelBuilder model is saved/exited/crashed/etc. it has the chance of getting corrupt in a quite weird way. The model can still be used as a tool, the only thing that is different is that all the tools that were incorporated in the model are changed from being yellow editable boxes to white lines, which can't be opened nor edited. The model becomes uneditable when this happens. It seemingly happens by pure random chance.

Sometimes this problem can be fixed by opening another model and opening the corrupt one again, or deactivating some extensions. The corrupted model then changes back to normal and can be accessed like normal. But sometimes it seems I can't get my models back to their normal layout.

Here is a picture of the effect of this bug:

[image]

The tools can't be opened/edited, while the results and input data can be edited.

Does anyone know a workaround to repair this problem/prevent this from happening?

Comment: What are these extensions you deactivate?

Comment: spatial analyst, 3d analyst, data interoperability

Comment: I have the same problems as you have. At random times it just goes white. If I dont save before closing I can still keep it. Very weird.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a possible solution to this problem;

When I copy the entire 'corrupt' model into a new modelbuilder model, the tools appear to be functioning as they should.

Comment: funny reasoning for closing the topic ... 'cause JTR is arguing that the problem seems to be random. ... the problem still exists and it is somehow random ! just now iv'e tried to open dozens of models (originally built in 10.3) in 10.4 and each of them is corrupted in that way ... and there is kind of a solution (which actually is not really satisfying ...) you don't even have to copy the model into a new one. just ctrl-x and ctrl-v the model into the same model. the real drawback: non of the labels you had in your original model will survive .. they just disappear.